# Concatanating array by While on Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, while-loop, raw-input

I had some question on python,

I am trying to write something, where after each raw-input , I should input into program some data (with array form). Then this data (arrays 2 dimensioanl ) should be added to the other 2 D array Full of zeros. Then when I input the second data (it should be again changed to 2 D array) and must be added to array Which already contain the array with Zeros and array from input). And so , after each input , array should be added already created arrays. Here is the code.

```
from numpy import *

var=zeros(shape=(1,11)) #making 2D array with zeros

while True: 

    file=raw_input("write data file name or path")

    c=open(file, 'r')
    ArrayStr=loadtxt(c, dtype='S',) #making array

    var=vstack((ArrayStr, var)) # concatantaing array 
print var
```

So finally I am getting array, which have only 2 arrays concatanatted (arrays with zeros and last inputted data array)

Thanks for attention and help

Comment: Your code looks OK, what exactly is the question? From what I understand, when you input `n` data file names, instead of the expected array of shape `(n, 11)` you get one of shape `(2, 11)`?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well I am using  using the shape=(1,11) vstack, because  I should have the same number of string in each array. But anyway my question is : . SO how can I get after each input of the Array, it to be added the old already concattanated array?

Comment: Here is the result of first input.                                                                        write data file name or patC:\Users\Lena\Desktop\PYTHON tASKS\POSM.txt
[['ATOM' '1' 'C1' 'POS' 'X' '1' '16.774' '117.860' '10.374' '1.00' '0.00']
  ['0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0']]

Comment: After second input it should be  should                         [['ATOM' '1' 'C1' 'POS' 'X' '1' '16.774' '117.860' '10.374' '1.00' '0.00']
  ['0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0']                                                                      ['ATOM' '1' 'C1' 'POS' 'X' '1' '16.774' '117.860' '10.374' '1.00' '0.00']

Comment: But it still concatanate only last inputted array with Array of Zeros

Comment: What is the purpose of your program?

Comment: What is your expected output after second input? Do you need the array with zeros to be in between the arrays containing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working code**

***in1.txt***

```
ATOM
1
C1
POS
X
1
16.774
117.860
10.374
1.00
0.00
```

***in2.txt***

```
ATOM
2
C2
POS
X
2
18.774
17.860
30.374
2.00
0.00
```

**Code**

```
import numpy

zeros = numpy.zeros(shape=(1,11)) #making 2D array with zeros

var = None

for i in range(1, 3):
    i1 = open("in" + str(i) + ".txt")

    a = numpy.loadtxt(i1, dtype='S')

    if var is None:
        var = numpy.vstack((a, zeros))
    else:
        var = numpy.vstack((var, a, zeros))

print var
```

**Output**

```
>>> 
[['ATOM' '1' 'C1' 'POS' 'X' '1' '16.774' '117.860' '10.374' '1.00' '0.00']
 ['0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0']
 ['ATOM' '2' 'C2' 'POS' 'X' '2' '18.774' '17.860' '30.374' '2.00' '0.00']
 ['0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0']]
>>>
```